# What to use instead of postDelayed to conserve memory

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my application I use a handler with multiple runnables. To call these runnables I loop postDelayed so they act as timers. I realized over time this generates a massive heap (10mb and continues to increase). So my question is what can i use instead of postDelayed that wont generate a massive heap of messages?

Comment: Maybe try `CountdownTimer` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: why do you think posting runnables consumes a lot of memory? reference please.

Comment: my question from yesterday someone answered saying dont use postdleayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that your runnables consumes so much memory. Each runnable instance should be cleared by GC after it is processed. If you are creating and posting runnables faster then they are executed  you would get ANR because your UI thread wouldn't be able to dispatch input events. If you create new runnables often it will cause GC to trigger more often but your heap shouldn't grow.

It's more likely that you have memory leaks in your app. You can use MAT to check what exactly consumes a lot of memory in java heap.

Comment: do you have any good guides on using mat because i dont know really how to tell if its a leak or not.

Comment: As for MAT you could start from [there](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).
Why did you decide that android.os.Message are taking 10mb? How many instances of them do you have? Message itself is really light object so 10MB possibly is retained heap size. And I think it will be clearer if you show your code where postDelayed is called.

Comment: theres about 25 different places it is called and yesbyou are right with it being retaioned heap size. Why would it be retaoning so much memory? Is it because Im keeping a reference to the runmable? Sorry im new to memory analysis.

Comment: As your runnables are likely to be anonymous inner classes they have implicit link to the outer class and thus whole `Activity` object may leak through runnable. The most frequent case is that you don't stop posting runnables when `Activity` is detstroyed.

Comment: thabk you for your explanation it helped solve 1 memory leak. The retained heap forms without changing activities though so what else could be causing it?